# Error when copying from a PDF into file name

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader

I look at lots of research papers, usually PDFs.  I open them, copy the title from the PDF using Adobe Acrobat Reader, close the file, click the file name and paste the title in.  This calls an error.  What's up with that?

> A file name can not contain any of the following symbols: *(standard list like / \ and so on)*

Just to be clear, my file name doesn't contain any of these symbols, or so I can't see them.

I just did a random file... I searched online for graph theory notes, first one is

http://users.utu.fi/harju/graphtheory/graphtheory.pdf

I downloaded it, copied the full title and tried to paste it into the name and it didn't work.

Comment: Which exactly? Does it happen to all, or only some? Give us an example!

Comment: Sorry, first off, I don't have any of those symbols in my file name.  I didn't make that clear and that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem but the only solution I could come up with was:

1. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) title of journal in PDF
2. Remember the last words of each line of the title.
3. Close PDF file
4. Slow double-click (or Rclick->rename) pdf file to rename
5. paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) copied title
6. For each last word of the real title (the edit file name box is limited, changing the length of lines of the pasted title), imagine there is an invisible, "illegal" character. Delete that space and add the space again.
7. Voila. Windows will now accept the new filename.

However, in my case, I have to change about 3,000 PDF filenames and haven't found a way to make this process quicker...

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> "A file name can not contain any of the following symbols … \" - What's up with that?

The "\" character is reserved for separating the names of directories (folders) from each other and  from the filename.

For example If I have a folder `c:\foo` containing a subdirectory `bar` and I put a file named `file.txt` into `bar` I could refer to it as `c:\foo\bar\file.txt`. If I were also allowed to put '\' in a filename, I could put into `c:\foo` a file named `bar\file.txt` and Windows would then have two different files in two different directories that could both be referred to by the same name `c:\foo\bar\file.txt`. This would cause problems.

Other characters also have special meanings and so are not accepted as part of the file name.

---

Update:

According to Adobe Reader (File, Properties, Description, Title) the title of http://users.utu.fi/harju/graphtheory/graphtheory.pdf is "GraphTheory.dvi". I was able to cut that and paste it into a file name.

The first two lines of the text in the PDF are "Lecture Notes on", "GRAPH THEORY". I cut those out and pasted them into a file name - this resulted in a file name of "Lecture notes on". I didn't get the error message you refer to.

---

Update:

If I cut out *all* the text on the first page, this includes "email:" and ":" is one of those characters that is not allowed in file names (in Windows filesystems)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at all clear in my question, but I do understand this part.  The thing is, I don't see any of these symbols in my file names.  I have updated the question to be clear.

Comment: @Graphth: I can't reproduce your problem (see update to answer) - where are you getting the title from? (and what is it?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Very annoying indeed. Problem for me was it would only paste one line of a multi-line title.

SOLUTION:
With the PDF open:

1. Right click anywhere on the page
2. Click 'Document Properties'
3. Copy the title from the window that opens up -> this will now paste into the file name field.

:)